# How to specify "Array of Integers" type in React Native RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY macro

Tags: user-interface, components, native, react-native

I would like to pass an array of integers from my JS RN native UI component to my swift/objective-C code that accepts "[Int]" as a property.  Here are the ones that I tried with RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY:

```
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(dataArray, [int])
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(dataArray, int *)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(dataArray, Int *)
```

They all turned out as invalid types and caused Xcode exception in the switch statement in RCTComponentData.m code below due to nil value in the typeSignature:

```
    // Ordinary property handlers
    NSMethodSignature *typeSignature = [[RCTConvert class] methodSignatureForSelector:type];
    switch (typeSignature.methodReturnType[0]) {
```

I couldn't find a list of valid types anywhere and I am left guessing.  It would be nice to figure out what are the set of valid types that I can use with RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY as well.

**Update 11/12/2015 - working solution found , based on Nick Lockwood's suggestion I've made the following changes:**

*in a RN_MyCustomerViewManager.m file (you can name this file with whatever name as long as it is an Obj-C .m file that import the Obj-c bridging header file)*

```
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(dataArray, NSNumberArray)
```

*in MyCustomerView.swift file*

```
func setDataArray(dataArray: [Int]) {…}
```

or

```
func setDataArray(dataArray: [Int]?) {…}
```

Now the array of integers gets passed in.

**I also found out that the valid RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY types are defined in the React Native RCTConvert.h so have that file handy if you need to do your define own Native UI Component**

Comment: Note that you can also define new supported types by extending RCTConvert with a category. However those types also need to be Objective-C compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native is an Objective-C library so we only support the subset of Swift types that can be bridged to Objective-C.

The swift type `[Int]` can't be represented in Objective-C at all. The closest you can get is `NSArray<NSNumber *> *`, which is not directly compatible with `[Int]`. To export an NSNumber array property in React Native you would use

```
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(dataArray, NSNumberArray)
```

However what you'll probably need to do on the Swift side is either change the type to `[NSNumber]?` or possibly `[AnyObject]?` (note the ? suffix, since view properties are all nullable in React), or if you can't do that, export a second property with a different name of type `[AnyObject]?` and then in the setter for that property, map the value to your actual `[Int]` property.